# runtime error 400 VBA

Tags: vba, excel, userform

I really do not know I am doing wrong.
Excel was working perfectly fine until it broke in the middle of procedure.
I have fixed code but right now I have problems with opening excel form.

Every time I open excel workbook runtime error '400' shows up.

I do have this code that makes a mess.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
UserForm1.Show
End Sub
```

Now it also says:

```
Code execution has been interrupted.
```

Dont you know where the problem might be? 
Thx

Comment: Maybe there is no UserForm1???

Comment: Change your error options in the VBE to 'Break in class module' and try again.

Comment: Probably the error is in the userform initialize, if the userform can't open, then that will be the only place the for the debugger to highlight. Can you open the userform from the vba editor?

Comment: @Fratyx yes, there is - I have checked :D

Comment: @Rory I have tried it - no change: Now it also says:
      
    Code execution has been interrupted.

Comment: @ Davesexcel Yes, I can.. :) Now it also says:
      
    Code execution has been interrupted.

Comment: Error in the UserForm1's OnLoad method?

Comment: @HeadOverFeet Well then, post the code that's IN the Sub. Also try and debug it, tell us at which line it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have the form open: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264359.aspx

Comment: I have restarted my computer. Thank you!